# Code is not uploading in new aurdino mega

Tags: arduino, hardware

I am new(new purched board and me also) in arduino programming. when I am uploading my code in ardino mega board (using Aurdino 1.8.2) i am getting following error

```
Arduino: 1.8.2 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560, ATmega2560 (Mega 2560)"

Sketch uses 1482 bytes (0%) of program storage space. Maximum is 253952 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 8183 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 8192 bytes.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude -CC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega2560 -cwiring -PCOM3 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_393128/Blink.ino.hex:i 

avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Jan 17 2017 at 12:00:53
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM3
         Using Programmer              : wiring
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

How i solve this problem.
My setting are as follows
[image].
rest of them are as default. also my driver are up to date in device manager.

Answer (score 0):

First, try a loopback test. If that fails, you have a problem with the hardware most likely. If it passes, try replacing the avr directory with another version. Additionally, if pins 1 or 0 are connected to anything, this error could be caused. That is because these pins are used for Tx/Rx. Additionally, the bootloader for the mega will break if you use !!! in your code. If all of that fails to help, try reinstalling the FTDI drivers.

Comment: how to loopback test